# Grid как ItemsControl (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Реально ли использовать `Grid` как контейнер для элементов с `DataTemplate`? И если нет, то как привести ширину **первой** колонки всех `Grid` находящихся в `StackPanel` (желательно через `Binding`)

Пример моего xaml:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Children>
          <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=NameRow}"/>
          <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Path=Value1}"/>
          <Button Grid.Column="2" Content="Test"/>
        </Grid.Children>
      </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

как видно первый столбец это `Binding` к свойству `NameRow`, но если строки разной длинны то элементы как бы плывут в зависимости от `NameRow`. Как бы их выровнять по максимальной длине первой колонки из всех `Grid`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, Вам необходим выровнять столбы расположенные в разных `Grid`. Ниже абстрактный пример, который показывает как можно это решить:

```
<ItemsControl Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True" ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ItemsControl.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:MyFirstModelType}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                     <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Description" />
                     <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Value" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>         
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Description}" />
                <Slider Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding Value}" />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Models:MySecondModelType}">
            <Grid>
                 <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Description" />
                      <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="Value" />
                 </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>         
                 <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding Description}" />
                 <Slider Grid.Column="1" Value="{Binding Value}" />
           </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.Resources>
</ItemsControl>
```

Ключевой момент на который нужно обратить внимание, это:

1) Cвойство `SharedSizeGroup`, в качестве значения которого указана строка соответствия. Столбцы с одинаковой строкой соответствия будут выравниваться одинаково.

2) Свойство `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`, которое необходимо установить в `true` что бы все это дело заработало.

Comment: Да отлично всё заработало, даже если на форме несколько контролов от этого темлейта! Спасибо!

Comment: Всегда, пожалуйста )